# Random record selection and pagination in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, will-paginate

I need to select random 5 records in sqlite3 and paginate them.

```
def test
    add_breadcrumb "Age Test", ages_test_url
    @posts = Age.limit(5).order('RANDOM()')
    @posts = @posts.page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
end
```

The above code displays all the record but I need only 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try alternative syntax:

```
Age.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2).order('RANDOM()').limit(5)
```

However, what is the point of paginating a **random** set of elements. Every time a user visits the first "page" s/he will see elements other than s/he saw the first. The idea of paginating a randomized elements doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Hi Uzbekjon, Thanks for the help but that didn't work. To answer your question... I have a set of 10 posts and the user can select any number of questions say 4 or 6 or something like that and those question should be randomized.

Comment: That's the thing. Say user selects 6 questions. You would show them on 3 pages (2 per page). When a user clicks on page `2`, s/he will see 2 *new* random elements. In other words, an element that appeared on the first page may appear again on the second page! Do you know what I mean?

Comment: No there is no repetition of elements in my current coding... Say there are 10 elements user say 6 and out of these 10 any 6 elements needs to be displayed 2 per page

Comment: When a user clicks on second page, your query will run again getting random 2 elements for the current page. Your random element selection for the first page is not stored and reused on this second page. So, you might end up with the elements already shown on previous pages. Alternatively, just keep refreshing your second page and you will see that the second page is always displaying different elements.